# Problem with sending post request from jenkins pipeline to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to send post request from jenkins pipeline ( groovy ) to wordpress action.

I use HttpRequest Plugin for jenkins and code looks like

```
def reqBody = "{\"action\":\"action_name\"}"

def response = httpRequest consoleLogResponseBody: true, contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', httpMode: "POST", requestBody: reqBody, url:"http://websitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
```

After run job with this code I've got `408 Request Timeout`.
Even the action name or whatever is wrong I should get 400.
I checked also similar request sent from Postman to same wordpress action and everything work with 200 code status, so wordpress works well.
Ok so then I thought that the problem is with jenkins and I've tried to send request to https://postman-echo.com/post for test. And works. 
So the problem is only between jenkins and wordpress. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If problem between Jenkins and WordPress, then maybe it's a network config issue? BTW, the `content-type` is wrong. I believe it should be `application/json`

Comment: I'd go with `sh curl` or `wget` here. I've seen lot of problems with request from Groovy here on StackOverflow.